# How to pass arguements in Nested routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, nested-routes

How to pass id in Nested routes path? I need to send picture_id.

```
<% @histories.pictures.each do |sAV|  %>
 <td><div class='col-md-4 col-sm-5'> <%=image_tag sAV.pic (:medium) %></td>
 <%= link_to 'Delete', history_pictures_path(histories_id: sAV.histories_id, id: pictures.id), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the result of `@histories.pictures`?

Comment: I just need to delete.

Comment: Try this  `<%= link_to 'Delete', history_pictures_path(histories_id: sAV.histories_id, id: sAV.id), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @histories.pictures.each do |sAV|  %>
 <td><div class='col-md-4 col-sm-5'> <%=image_tag sAV.pic (:medium) %></td>
 <%= link_to 'Delete', history_pictures_path(history_id: sAV.history_id, id: sAV.id), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Try this

Comment: undefined method `histories_id'